# Problem with setting up NOOBS

Tags: setup

I intalled noobs and copy it onto my sd card (like [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/videos/)) then I connected my Pi with the PC by HDMI cable. After that I plug Pi in, and the only red light turns on but the second light turned on for less than one second. Now my screen does not show me anything. I put my sd card back and it seems Pi renamed it 'SETTING' and edited the files and the capacity. Please help 
 ** I have Pi 3 and my OS is Ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HDMI port on your laptop is an output. You can NOT connect the Pi to a laptop via HDMI and use the laptop's screen. However, you will need a screen and keyboard to configure noobs the first time.

You can however, download Raspbian and burn that to your SD card. Unlike noobs Raspbian can be setup headless, using SSH.

Comment: Thank you  .. that makes sense .. but this man did that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VmlfO7wL40 at 5:35 .. and I have another question please should I format my sd card ?

Comment: No he plugs it into a monitor. At 5:34 of the video he connects the Pi to a monitor.

Comment: Yes it worked when I connected to the TV. Thank you

Comment: @RMSH glad I could help